# 404 Not found, The requested url was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.52 (ubuntu) wp-admin page for wordpress website

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2

Hi so I have recently started building a website on an amazon aws EC2 Ubuntu vm instance and have successfully started the site with apache2, the website itself works but when I try to enter the wp-admin page It says 404 Not found, The requested url was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.52 (ubuntu).

This is my 000-default.conf file,

```
`<VirtualHost *:80># The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.#ServerName www.example.com
```

```
    <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress

    

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ServerName tektalk4kids.com
    ServerAlias www.tektalk4kids.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

```
vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet`
```

If anyone can help me out I would really appreciate it because I have been stuck on this problem for a long time.

I tried Allowoveride All and activated the rewrite model and restarted apache2 multiple times.

Comment: You are denying all access. Add these two lines `Order allow,deny` and `allow from all`. Review the documentation for `<VirtualHost>`. Note: I recommend that you follow a good tutorial. You should have disabled `000-default.conf`, created a new site in `sites-available`, and then enabled that site. You are missing a basic understanding of Apache site management. Digital Ocean writes excellent tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a mod rewrite issue.

**some points to check:**

1. Do you have correct permissions for apache user (possibly www-data)?
   The user should have read and execute permissions for wp-admin folder.
2. for mod-rewrite did you install the module on apache.

to install mod rewrite:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-rewrite
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

3. did you modify .htaccess file with suggested wordpress directives? Check this for examples https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/
4. If it is not resolved please provide more details.